# Formula to find the most recent Monday

Tags: excel, datetime

I hate Mondays.  Don't you?

I'm trying to write a formula the will display the date of the most recent Monday.  For example, today is 7/6/2011, and the most recent Monday was 7/4/2011.

I tried `=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+2`, but this formula hates Sundays, and fails if TODAY is 7/3/2011

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3)
```

Adding the `3` parameter makes `WEEKDAY` return a value from 0 (Monday) to 6 (Sunday).